# Is there a way in jQuery Cycle to retrieve a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

Is there a way, in [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), to retrieve a parameter?

**Example**

```
$('#slider').cycle({speed: 750})
```

How can I, in Javascript/jQuery, retreive the value 750?
**I tried**
`console.log( $('#slider').cycle.speed )`
`console.log( $('#slider').cycle.('speed') )`

but the value is `undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any plugin [commands](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) which allow you to retrieve the value. However, exploring the results with Firebug, it appears that the plugin stores its options under the `cycle.opts` data attribute. If you really need to get at the value, you can use:

```
$('#pics').data("cycle.opts").speed
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWDa4/

Note that this is **not an ideal solution** since there's no guarantee that it will continue to work with future updates.

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be:

```
console.log($("#slider").cycle("speed"));
```

Or

```
var s = $("#slider").cycle();
console.log(s.speed);
```

Not having it to test means I can't be 100% sure, but all the options are here (as you probably know)
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

The final option is to change the approach:

```
var speed = 750
$("#slider").cycle({"speed: " + speed });
```

Then you have the speed as a seperate variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jquery.data(element,key,value) .
Eg: jquery.data($('#slider'),cycle,speed)